# Validation returns empty array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

**Model:**

```
protected $validationRules = [
    'username' => 'required'
];
protected $validationMessages = [
    'username' => [
        'required' => 'Please enter a username'
    ]
];
```

**Controller:**

```
 if($this->request->getMethod()== 'post'){
    
                $usermodel = new \App\Models\Users;
                $User = $usermodel
                ->where('username' , $this->request->getPost('username'))
                ->first();
    
                if(!$User){
                    print_r($usermodel->errors());
                    /*return redirect()->to('/login')->with('errors' , $usermodel->errors())->withInput();*/
                }
```

**View:**

```
<?php if(session()->has('errors')): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach(session('errors') as $error): ?>
                
                    <li><?= $error ?></li>
                
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know I have commented out the return statement. I got the same empty array with print_r() in the controller and also with "return redirect with view" .

**BUT:** If I specify manually the flash message in controller, then I got the "Wrong pw" message:

```
 if(!$UserFromDB){
                return redirect()->to('/login')->with('errors' , array('Wrong pw'))->withInput();
                /*print_r($usermodel->errors());*/
                /*return redirect()->to('/login')->with('errors' , $usermodel->errors())->withInput();*/
 }
```

Comment: sorry but why is laravel tagged in your question ?

Comment: sorry I have removed

Comment: I'm afraid I don't use model based validation (I do it controller side) so this is just a couple of thoughts. Can you confirm `protected $skipValidation     = false;`  as per https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html? and also that `$model->getValidationRules()` returns your rules correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we use form validation in the model, but rather in the controller. this is how i proceed

```
#Controller     
if($this->request->getMethod()== 'post'){
$rules = ['username' => ['rules' => 'required];
$messages = ["username" => [
                "required" => "Please enter a username",
            ],
        ];
if($this->validate($rules,$messages)){
// validation succeed
}
else{
// validation not ok
            $response = [
                'message' => $this->validator->getErrors()
            ];
            
            $data['response'] = $response;
            //  redirect to your login view        
        }
}
```